# Is it possible to get number of users watching a stream?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video-streaming

I'm using a regular flash video player to play rtmp streams hosted on a cdn. Does anyone know if it is possible to get a count of the number of users watching a stream, through actionscript or flash?

Comment: what CDN is it? Most come with reporting that can tell you how many people are watching

Answer (score 0):

You could have every viewer generate a unique identifier, and every so often (5 seconds, for example) they send in a tidbit with their identifier to a script that counts up all the unique id's sent in. The script would return the number of unique id's counted in the last minute or so.